# R - how to merge rows from 1 data set by ID, with different data

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

ID     WhereEaten
1      restaurant
1      home
2      hospital
3      camp
4      restaurant
4      grocery store

I want to merge the rows by ID, and combine the values of WhereEaten to look like this:

ID     WhereEaten
1restaurant, home
2      hospital
3      camp
4      restaurant, grocery store

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can do `aggregate(WhereEaten~ID, df, toString)`

Comment: Thanks akrun. This did not work for me, and neither did the suggestion from the other post. This is what I did...     
aggregate(Query1$WherePrepName~Query1$CDCID, Query1, toString)  
Query1                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
library(plyr)        
ddply(Query1, .(CDCID), summarize, WherePrepName = toString(WherePrepName))  
Query1

Comment: From the example you posted, it is working fine for me